# Chrome Dev Tools Elements Broken on Mobile Device Inspect

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome (40.0.2214.28), Chromium, and Canary when inspecting a website on any phone you can not click on elements like you can when you're inspecting a desktop site.

The **only** way to change what element you're inspecting in the DOM is with the arrow keys which takes way way way longer.

Is there any way to fix Chrome to be able to inspect mobile devices correctly?